# Export and import Visual Composer design across sites

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

I've designed a site at my own domain and I now want to implement the same design on a clients domain.

All is done in Visual Composer and the clients site have the exact same conditions and plugins for a migration to work, but I can't seam to find a "export Visual Composer design" option anywhere on the web!

The hard way to do it is to have two windows open and manually create the same design by going element to element, tab to tab, which really isn't an option...

The Templatera plugin only seam to work on the same domain.

Does anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 4):

I have discovered an easiest way.
This is just change the layout to text. or deactivate the visual composer plugins. then it will show only a written code on each page.

Just copy the codes in the page from where you want to copy and paste the code to other domain's page where you want to put.

Then reactivate the visual composer plugins in both site.

Comment: Visual Composer store attachment IDs rather than URLs. When moving to a different site, the attachment IDs will obviously be different and it causes a lot of trouble replacing images. Does anyone know a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Building on Ali Hayder Shawon answer, here's a simple solution that does not require to deactivate the plugin:

1. **Click on the "Classic mode" button in the source editor** (screenshot below).
2. **Select all text in the text editor** (screenshot below).
3. **Paste it in the destination editor**, making sure that it is too in classic mode.

## Screenshot for step 1:

[image: screenshot]

## Screenshot for step 2:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You need save your design to to My Templates (Saved Templates), then you can export and import to client site. I know a free plugin can do it, try search "VC Templates Import & Export".